# Why is a special company's product shown through out a film?

Tags: product-placement

Today I completed [Bourne Trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_%28film_series%29) and noticed a thing very interesting. They used Motorola as cell phone for each person in the movie which is very impractical. I have seen such thing in other movies also. Motorola as cellphone for each cast is shown in [Don](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_%282006_Hindi_film%29) and Audi in [transporter movie series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Transporter_%28film_series%29) or [Aston Martin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_James_Bond_vehicles#Aston_Martin) in Bond series. So is it done to promote the products thorough the films? Or do the companies sponsor the films?

Comment: checkout [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_placement#Product_placement_in_movies) about product placement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Motorola was a huge sponsor of the Bourne Trilogy, even doing an advanced screening of the films for VIPs. [This article](http://www.techdigest.tv/2007/08/13_technologyre.html) from TechDigest chronicles all of the high tech product placements in Bourne Ultimatum. Sadly, product placement is becoming so blatant that it is becoming distracting!

As you say, it is done to promote the products by associating them with certain types of characters.

Comment: The phrase "certain types of characters" adds a lot to the answer. Generally companies wouldn't want their products to be used in 'sadistic/psycho' scenes or associated with villains (ex: a psycho killer) as it may send a negative message to the audience instead of any positive promotion of the product.

Comment: [This post](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/4305/why-did-aaron-cross-take-the-watch-from-the-security-chief) about Alex Cross's watch elaborates on the subject.